# Exchange EWSMA FindFolders Unexpected Token in Xml

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

we are reading some user folders with this code

```
FolderId id = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, userIdentity);
FindFoldersResults ffr = service.FindFolders(id, new FolderView(999));
```

The UserIdentity is a  normal boring E-Mailadress like abc.cde@domain.com But from one user we get an XmlException (s. below)

All other users with similar mailadresses are working.

Any hints ? May this be a bug in the EWSMA ?

Here the stacktrace:

> System.Xml.XmlException: '>' is an unexpected token. The expected
>   token is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 63.    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy.System.Xml.IDtdParserAdapter.Throw(Exception
>   e)    at System.Xml.DtdParser.Throw(Int32 curPos, String res, String[]
>   args)    at System.Xml.DtdParser.ThrowUnexpectedToken(Int32 pos,
>   String expectedToken1, String expectedToken2)    at
>   System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseExternalId(Token idTokenType, Token
>   declType, String& publicId, String& systemId)    at
>   System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseInDocumentDtd(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
>   at System.Xml.DtdParser.Parse(Boolean saveInternalSubset)    at
>   System.Xml.DtdParser.System.Xml.IDtdParser.ParseInternalDtd(IDtdParserAdapter
>   adapter, Boolean saveInternalSubset)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDtd()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read()    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read()    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read(XmlNodeType
>   nodeType)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   ewsXmlReader)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(HttpWebResponse
>   response)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.InternalExecute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalFindFolders(IEnumerable`1
>   parentFolderIds, SearchFilter searchFilter, FolderView view,
>   ServiceErrorHandling errorHandlingMode)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindFolders(FolderId
>   parentFolderId, FolderView view)

[...]

Answer (score 1):

You should first share the exact version of Exchange you are using.

This could be a bug in Exchange, but it's highly unlikely. I would first capture the HTTP response coming back from EWS using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). You should share back your response stream here. It sounds like one of the mailbox folder names could be causing some issues with the `EwsXmlReader`.

You could also enable [EWS Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633676%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) as suggested in this [MSDN forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/9d1286f6-d02f-4924-9e37-9136eac06031).